# Why I am getting null check error for a function with default parameter?

Tags: flutter

My problem is, I am getting "null check operator used on a null value" error. As you know, it is darts default null check error.

And I am getting this error on default parameter. So It can't be possible but why I am getting this error ?

for quick search: "buttonColor??backgroundColor!" -> this line. Background color has a optional value.

All my code is below. Thank you a lot :)

```
class FormButtons extends GestureDetector {
  FormButtons.textButton({
    Key? key,
    required String buttonText,
    required FutureOr<void> Function()? onTap,
    Color? borderColor,
    Color? backgroundColor,
    Color? textColor=const FormColors.black3()
  }) : super(
    key: key,
    onTap: onTap,
    child: _formButtonFrame(
      borderColor: borderColor,
      backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
      child: _formButtonText(buttonText, textColor!)
    )
  );
}



Container _formButtonFrame({
  required Widget child,
  Color? buttonColor,
  Color? borderColor=Colors.transparent,
  Color? backgroundColor=Colors.transparent
}){
  print(backgroundColor==null);
  print((backgroundColor??backgroundColor)==null);
  print("x");
  print((backgroundColor??backgroundColor)==null);
  print((backgroundColor??backgroundColor)==Colors.transparent);
  print("_formButtonFrame");
  return Container(
    padding: FormEdgeInsets.formButtonsPadding(),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: buttonColor??backgroundColor!,
      boxShadow: [
        BoxShadow(color: borderColor!, spreadRadius: 1.0.sp),
      ]
    ),
    child: child,
  );
}
```

And console output is like;

```
I/flutter (12737): true
I/flutter (12737): true
I/flutter (12737): x
I/flutter (12737): true
I/flutter (12737): false
I/flutter (12737): _formButtonFrame
```

And I am just calling this widget

```
Widget get _defaultTextButton=>FormButtons.textButton(
      buttonText: "Default Text Button",
      onTap: ()=>print("_defaultTextButton")
  );
```

Comment: You used `backgroundColor!` as the default value when `buttonColor` (a different variable) is `null`, and `print(backgroundColor==null)` printed `true`.  You used `!` on a `null` value.

Comment: @jamesdlin, but how can backgroundColor become null, I am giving default value as "Colors.transparent", so Isn't it must be Colors.transparent ? Can u explain it to me ?

Comment: `_formButtonFrame` specifies a default argument for `backgroundColor`, but the default is used only if no argument is supplied by the caller.  It does not prevent a caller from calling `_formButtonFrame(backgroundColor: null)`.  If you don't want it to be `null`, don't make it nullable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write:

```dart
Container _formButtonFrame({
  ...
  Color? backgroundColor=Colors.transparent
}){
```

you are specifying a default argument to use if the caller omits the argument entirely.  However, because `backgroundColor` uses a nullable type, the caller can still *explicitly* pass a `null` argument:

```dart
_formButtonFrame(
  ...
  backgroundColor: null,
  ...,
)
```

which is effectively what happens in the `FormButtons.textButton` constructor where it forwards its own `backgroundColor` argument.

If you don't want `backgroundColor` to ever be `null`, don't make it nullable. (This will require fixing all callers, however, and it also will make it harder for callers to forward arguments.)

If you instead want `null` to use the `Colors.transparent` default, you can move the default value into the function body:

```dart
Container _formButtonFrame({
  ...
  Color? backgroundColor,
}) {
  backgroundColor ??= Colors.transparent;
```